# IE pop-up reference from Edge browser

Tags: internet-explorer, popup, microsoft-edge, popupwindow

I'm having an issue with opening pop-up window which loads in IE compatibility mode due to group policy (legacy web-application which runs on IE).
The parent window has to load in Edge which invokes a function and passes some parameters to the pop-up window.
Noticed that I'm neither able to access the pop-up window through object reference from window.open() not able to send event/data using postMessage(). And as expected, not able to get parent window handle from pop-up using window.opener().
It all works totally fine if I load the parent window in IE but cannot force that as other functionalities on that screen won't work with IE.

Note: As data from parent to pop-up window can sometimes be quite large, passing it using query string is not an option as it has limitation on max chars.

I got a feeling that as IE and Edge are different browser platforms, the communication is broken. Appreciate any help on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: According to your description, do you mean that you need to open the parent page in `Edge`, and use window.open to open the child page in `Edge IE mode`? If this is the case, then this is impossible. As you might guess, they are different browsers and cannot communicate.

Comment: That's correct. Parent page opens in Edge and child pop-up window opens in Edge IE mode due to group policy (forces it to open in IE mode). Get the point that they're built on different browser engines and realize that they can't communicate the hard way - tried event listeners, cookies and what not.
Looking for suggestions on passing data from parent window to child in this scenario.

Comment: Well, if you only want to use different browsers to achieve communication, I think this is impossible. If the browser interacts with the server and then sends the request through the server, I think this is possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check link below.
Since version 96 it's possible to include almost everything on navigation between modes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#internetexplorerintegrationcomplexnavdatatypes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32752209)